# Compound Where Clause in LINQ not working correctly

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I have a screen where the user can enter in different values to add to the WHERE clause.  When I test with just 1 value my code works fine. When I test with more than 1 value, the result sets are always 0.

I have validated the data in the database and the data coming from the form are as expected.  Them multiple items in the WHERE predicate are not matching correctly.

whereClause is of type Dictionary

```
      var lazydata = (from item in db.ComplaintLogWithRetailer
                            select item);
            string val = "";

            if (whereClause != null)
            {
                if (whereClause.Keys.Contains("CaseYear"))
                {
                    val = whereClause["CaseYear"];
                    lazydata = lazydata.Where(w => w.CaseYearOnly.ToString().Equals(val));
                }

                if (whereClause.Keys.Contains("AssignedTo"))
                {
                    val = whereClause["AssignedTo"];
                    lazydata = lazydata.Where(w => w.Initials.ToString().Equals(val));
                }

                if (whereClause.Keys.Contains("CaseNumber"))
                {
                    val = whereClause["CaseNumber"];

                    lazydata = lazydata.Where(w => w.CaseNumber.ToString().Equals(val));
                }


                //if (whereClause.Keys.Contains("CountyId"))
                //    data = lazydata.Where(w => w.Count.ToString().Equals(whereClause["CountyId"])).ToList();


                if (whereClause.Keys.Contains("ClassCode"))
                    lazydata = lazydata.Where(w => w.ClassCode.ToString().Equals(whereClause["ClassCode"]));


                if (whereClause.Keys.Contains("DateReceived"))
                    lazydata.Where(w => w.ReceivedDate.ToString().Equals(whereClause["DateReceived"]));


                if (whereClause.Keys.Contains("RetailerNumber"))
                    lazydata = lazydata.Where(w => w.RetailerNumber.ToString().Equals(whereClause["RetailerNumber"]));


                data = lazydata.ToList();

                //data = lazydata.ToList<ComplaintLogWithRetailer>();

                //data = (from item in lazydata
                //        select item).ToList();
            }
```

There are 5 records with a year of 2018 and 1 of those records has AssignedTo of 'BCC' I am expecting 1 records back but always get 0 records when 2 or more '.Where" operations are performed

Comment: Your assigning a new value to `val` in subsequent then portions of `if` for second where but that means the lambda for the first where will also get the new value - a lambda creates a closure over a variable, which means it doesn't use the value at the time the lambda is created, but at the time the lambda is called (or in the case of LINQ, translated to SQL). So put separate `var val = ` in each then portion.

Comment: @NetMage Thank you so much!  Makes total sense now that you pointed it out.